# Using Mean value theorem for infinity

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is it possible to use the Mean value theorem:
$f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$
for $(a,\infty)$
when I know the f is differentiable at $(a,\infty)$ ?

I have a problem like this:
f is differentiable at $(a,\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$

I need to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}=0} $

Comment: no you have to use it on $]x,x+1[$ for example with $x>a$ and let $x\to\infty $.

Comment: How do you suggest solving my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of
[L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{1} = 0
$$
but can also be shown directly using the Mean-Value Theorem:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$ there is a $x_0 > 0$
such that $|f'(x)| < \varepsilon$ for $x \ge x_0$. It follows that

$$
   |f(x)| = |f(x_0) + (x - x_0)f'(c)| \text{ for some } c \in (x_0,  x) \\
      \le  |f(x_0)| + \varepsilon (x - x_0)  \le  |f(x_0)| + \varepsilon \, x
$$
and therefore

$$
   \left | \frac {f(x)}x \right | \le \varepsilon + \left| \frac {f(x_0)}x \right |
$$

Now choose $x_1 \ge x_0$ such that $\left| \frac {f(x_0)}{x_1} \right | < \varepsilon$.
Then
$$
\left | \frac {f(x)}x \right | < 2\varepsilon \text { for } x > x_1 \quad \text {(*)}
$$

So for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $x_1 > 0$ such that (*) holds,
which proves that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$